# add Node.js gm to project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use the GraphicsMaker node.js gm lib in my web app ( https://github.com/aheckmann/gm ) but I'm getting Script error from require.js when trying to get the lib and it's not finding gm.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/gm.js 404 (Not Found) require.min.js:34
Uncaught Error: Script error for: gm
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.min.js:8
C require.min.js:8
i.onScriptError
```

Do I need to compile the gm folder or something before using it?
I used

> npm intall gm

to get it but, as I said, do I need to do something more with it before I can use it?
I'm not finding a lot of information about it on Google so would really appreciate some help from anyone who knows how to use this.

Thansk!

Comment: That lib is for nodejs to control GM on the backend, not for front end javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use `gm` client-side which isn't the right way to go about it.

From the [description page](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/):

> First install either GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick.

...If you already have GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick installed, `gm` is ready for use.

Just keep in mind that it's a server-side module. To recreate the effect on `gm`'s description page, you'd have to add an image to your page and when someone clicks on one of the effect buttons, you'd do an AJAX request to the server where it would apply the effect and return the new image:

```
//So this is on the server-side, in an Express.JS route for instance:
gm('/path/to/my/img.jpg')
.resize(240, 240) //As an example, we'll just resize an image
.noProfile()
.toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(body));
    res.end(body);
});
```

I don't know if you use Express.js or not. If you don't the code needs to be adjusted a little. If you let me know in a comment, I can adjust the code sample accordingly.

Comment: Ok, well I'm using Backbone.js and the backbone router.